# ExtJS - capture all events

Tags: extjs, extjs5

To capture all the events for an object, various searches say all I have to do is use:

```
Ext.util.Observable.capture(object, function(stuff){console.log(stuff);});
```

But I get the error:

```
Ext.util.Observable.capture is not a function
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug in Ext JS, but you can still use `Ext.mixin.Observable.capture` instead.

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/spuy8cob/).